# Python-for-android AttributeError : avdmanager bug when building with buildozer and Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, google-colaboratory, buildozer, python-for-android

I am currently trying to build an app with buildozer and kivy, and it worked well so far. When I tried to add a feature a build it using a buildozer it caused me an error 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stdout'' coming from the build file of python-for-android installed automatically via buildozer and now I can't build anyting anymore, using a Google Colab environment or my own buildozer setup with WSL Ubuntu. Is it related to my code or a recent python-for-android issue ?

I tried 'buildozer android -v debug' and it caused this error on every setup i used to build it via buildozer. Removing the newly added requirements and permissions off of my buildozer.spec didn't change the error log either. I also tried to build with p4a branch master and develop and it didn't change anyting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue, I just edited the error file and remove stdout.

from :

```
avdmanager('list', 'target').stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

to :

```
avdmanager('list', 'target').split('\n')
```

Comment: i think the error on file build.py and recipe.py

Comment: Removing every occurence of "stdout.decode('utf-8')" one erro log at a time without cleaning the .buildozer folder did it for me, thanks a lot !

Comment: I added an issue on github and pasted this solution:
https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1561
Please upvote to get it fixed

Comment: The devs replied and said they fixed the issue in this release: 
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/releases/tag/v2023.02.10

If you clean and run buildozer again now, the issue doesn't occur